# how to use document.execCommand with different scenarios?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've used document.execCommand("ForeColor",false,"Red") and it makes the font as red color. But it is not a good standard of HTML5. In order that, we need to use css class. But, it is more complex to use it. Let me give an example, I have a text like "ABC DEF". suppose if i select "BC" and exec the command and BC becomes red in color. and now if user select "AB" and I want "A" becomes black in color and B becomes combination of black and red in color. How to achieve this using document.execCommand.